# CSS same text width in php echo date using google font

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I am using a google font to display all text and numbers on my site it works fine but now I got a problem with the follow thing:

Date example in the table for search resuts

```
2014-11-12 text and some text
2014-12-28 text and some text
```

The results shows 25 dates (results) but the date is not using the same width because the font does not show the same width while using numbers 11 as when using 28 I mean is not the same width so the column in the tables looks bad.

I would like the date with the format 2014-02-28 to be the same text width in the column but cannot figure out how to do it

I created a fiddle and it works fine but not on my site I dont understand why here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a2otstLf/

Comment: If the fiddle works but not your site then link the site .... It's impossible to make an assumption about your code without seen it

Answer (score 0):

If it works in fiddle it means there`s a problem with your website.

Maybe u messed up something in .css file? Removed some lines?

Maybe ur including the wrong .css file to your website?